# Need to dynamically check for a record and insert if not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, dynamic-sql

I wanted to write as script that checks if a record exists in a table, and insert if it doesn't exist. I want to run it in different databases dynamically.

```
SELECT 1 from 
(SELECT parameter as parameter from @db_name.dbo.Table) a
WHERE parameter = 'new record'
if it doesn't retrieve a value
BEGIN 
INSERT
```

I was trying to use a dynamic sql, but I stuck. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use MS SQL 2014

Comment: Why do you want/need to use dynamic SQL here? There's nothing dynamic in your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check with `if exists`

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from dbo.Table WHERE parameter = 'new record')
  BEGIN
    -- INSERT
  End 
ELSE 
  BEGIN
    -- UPDATE
  END
```

but if you want to do it in dynamic sql :

```
declare @dbname varchar(100) 
        ,@sqlstring nvarchar(4000)
-- to avoid SQL injection you can do :
IF ( SELECT OBJECT_ID(@dbname+'.dbo.Table')) is not null 
   BEGIN
set @sqlstring = 'IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from'+@dbname+'.dbo.Table WHERE parameter = ''new record'')
  BEGIN
    -- INSERT
  End 
ELSE 
  BEGIN
    -- UPDATE
  END'
END
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstring
```

Comment: Thanks @eshirvana. This would work in a single database, but I want to do it in multiple databases.... every time I run it in a new database, db_name should be changed dynamically. Any help?

Comment: if the table name  is alwayas the same , you just don't need to mention database name 'dbo.tablename` , just make connection to the right db

Comment: Warning, that dynamic statement is wide open to injection attacks. *Always* properly quote your dynamic object names with `QUOTENAME`. You also don't explain how you would execute the dynamic statement to the OP here.

Comment: Thanks @eshirvana... it is a good guide. However, I'm having trouble with it. For the detail, please check this. I couldn't put it as a comment here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65725512/in-dynamic-sql-unclosed-quotation-mark-and-incorrect-syntax-near